# Angular 6: HttpErrorResponse SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I am posting a request and I am suppose to receive a 'success' string back as response. I am getting an HttpResponseError with the following information posted in the image below.

[image]

PurchaseOrderService

```
postPurchaseOrderCustom(purchaseOrderCustom: PurchaseOrderSaveCustom) {
 const url = `${this.localUrl}purchaseOrderCustom`;
 return this.http.post<String>(url, purchaseOrderCustom, {headers: this.header})
            .pipe(
                   catchError(this.handleError('postPurchaseOrderCustom', 'I am an error'))
                 );
  }
```

PurchaseOrderComponent

```
this.purchaseOrderService.postPurchaseOrderCustom(purchaseOrderCustom).subscribe( response => {
  console.log("Testing", response);
  },
  error => {
    console.error('errorMsg',error );   
  }
```

The way I am doing it is the same way its done in the documentation. Do point out to me what I am doing wrong.

[image: error shown when I implement answer provided by @Muhammed]

Comment: This is angular error realted to you api respond ,http object  by default try to parse you api respond it 's seen just plain text this why the throw this cand in error ,try this in you console `JSON.parse('Hi')` if you don't get my pont

Comment: Either wrap your response in quotes at the backend, or change the `responseType` to 'text' in the front end

Comment: @user184994 what do you mean by wrap in quotes in the backend, it is already in quotes and that makes it a string. That is if I am getting you write. And what happens if you are receiving an object back

Comment: Yep, but you need extra quotes, something like `"\"success\"". If you receiving a valid JSON object back, there won't be any issues, it depends on what you mean when you say "an object"

Comment: @user184994 Im using springboot as my backend and usually when you send an object it gets parsed as Json and is transformed to the corressponding Object in Angular. Thats if Im correct. So why is it different from a string object.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This related to your api respond type ,`success` is not valid json format,by default `HttpClient` is expected json response type and try to parse it later . You can solve this by set the respond type to **text** like this

```js
return this.http.post<String>(
    url,
    purchaseOrderCustom,
    { headers: this.header, responseType: 'text' }
)
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('postPurchaseOrderCustom', 'I am an error')
        ));
```

Comment: I had to add as 'json'. before it worked so if you can edit your answer so I accept it. 
{headers: this.header , responseType:'text' as 'json'})

Comment: did you add this to make it work  `responseType:'json'`

Comment: this is what I did `{headers: this.header , responseType:'text' as 'json'})` . just adding text didnt work for me. And from discussions from Github people added that to make it work

Comment: did you use Http or HttpClient ?

Comment: I use HttpClient, do you by the way know why this is

Comment: as operater is related to typescript if you remove it will work ,try this in typescript playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html ,let c = {headers: '' , responseType:'text' as 'json'}

Comment: if you check the chrome network panel you will see that the responseType is text,you just change the default respond type from json to text as I said in my answer

Comment: Albarmaw sorry didnt get what you meant , but when I remove the as json I get a squiggly line error and it doesnt compile till I add the as json.

Comment: do you know the usage of as operator ?  let b = '10' as number this mean '10' type is number but the b will be '10' this just related to typescript but the value still '10' but typescript will think b  type is number

Comment: thiss `responseType:'text' as 'json'` you just tell typescript the type of respondType is litiral value of 'json' but the value will be 'text' @user3701188

Comment: hope you got my point so   {headers: this.header , responseType:'text'} will work and the respond type is text so will not parse your respond and you will not got the error that you use to have

Comment: I do understand, but the problem here is your code gives me an error in the file, it give a red squiggly error and it doesnt compile when I do it the way you suggested

Comment: and when I add the as json it works fine and I dont get an error in my console again

Comment: This is what it says `Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.     Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json`

Comment: `{ headers: HttpHeaders; response Type: "text"; }` you separate the property with `;` semicolon and this is wrong just look to my answer it is `,` comma

Comment: it is the error that shows that my codes are exactly as your answer and it gives the error. I have updated a picture in the main question take a look at it and also take a look at the discussions provided in Github.
`https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586`

Comment: as the github issues show this consider a bug but it 's **close** and it 's since 12 month you may consider update your angular version if it 's old @user3701188

Comment: These are my angular dependencies so I think I am using the latest version  `"@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2"`

Comment: so i had to remove the cast that is <string> in order to make your way work, can you also take of the cast so I get to approve the answer

Answer (score 3):

Like it has already been said, this has everything to do with the response coming from your server.

In my case, I had a Spring Boot application that returned this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("Your SSN was generated successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
```

and this was the response I was getting on the Angular end:

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHtt…, text: "Your SSN was registered successfully."}
```

So what I did was create a custom `CustomHttpResponse` class in my Spring Boot application and then changed the code in my controller to this:

```
        ...
        CustomHttpResponse customHttpResponse = new CustomHttpResponse();
        customHttpResponse.setMessage("Your SSN was registered successfully.");
        customHttpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Gson().toJson(customHttpResponse), 
                                          HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Now I'm getting this:

```
{message: "Your SSN was registered successfully.", status: 200}
   message: "Your SSN was registered successfully."
       status: 200
```

Essentially,  this error occurs when Angular is expecting JSON but gets something else instead

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue while getting pdf data buffer in response and I handled it in following manner, it's working for me

server side

```
pdf.create(output, options).toBuffer((err: any, buffer: any) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
           response.type('pdf');
response.send(buffer);
        });
```

in Angular Service
downloadPdf(dateRange, labs){

```
return this.httpClient.post(url, data,{responseType:'blob'});
```

}
And in Component.ts file

```
downPdf1(){
    this.analyticService.downloadPdf(this.dateRange, this.labs).subscribe(
      res => this.extractPdf(res),
      (error:any) => throwError (error || 'Server error')
  );
  }

 extractPdf(res){
     let myBlob: Blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/pdf'}); 
     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
     window.open(fileURL);
 }
```